# Getting the real time and date in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, date

i am creating a webpage and i have a form inside of it. In one of my input box i want to set the current date automatically without the user inputting it. I am using the getDate() function of PHP but the problem is that people can change the date by changing their system date and time....

I want the real date and time.

```
$mydate=getdate(date("U"));
$date = "$mydate[weekday], $mydate[month] $mydate[mday], $mydate[year]";
<input value='$date'>
```

Help Guys

Answer (score 3):

PHP `date()` function gets time from your system. So that a user can change his system time and data will have that time.

A solution would be, have a Timestamp field in your database table (I'm assuming that you are going to save the form data in a database) and that will take the time from the server, where the database is hosted.

The user can't change the server's time, so that a correct time will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use date() function to set current date and time  automatically.
For example

```
 <?php echo '<input type=text value="' . date("d F Y H:i:s") . '" readonly/>';?>
```

d : Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros (01-31) 
F: A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March 
Y: full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits (2017) 
H: 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros (00 through 23) 
i: Minutes with leading zeros (00 to 59) 
s:Seconds, with leading zeros (00 to 59)

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided sets the dat according to the server's date and time and in not affected by the users' system date and time:
The one thing you can add so that the user cannot modify the date is the readonly flag:

```
$mydate=getdate(date("U"));
$date = "$mydate[weekday], $mydate[month] $mydate[mday], $mydate[year]";
```

The readonly attribute can be used like so:

```
<input value="<?php echo $date;?>" readonly="readonly">
```

OR

```
<input value="<?php echo $date; ?>" readonly>
```

If your code is inside php script then:

```
echo '<input value="'.$date.'" readonly>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a input like

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");?>" disabled>
```

More details about date function available at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

No real need to have it in the form - 
You can just handle the date on the other side of the post method.
like:

```
sql = CURDATE()
php = date("Y-md"); //or what ever format you fancy.
```